# rvalue reference not working when parameter is a parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

When I make an rvalue from a template parameter pack it does not compile, but if it is a 'simple' template parameter it compiles fine.

In this code `for_each_in_tup1` compiles fine, but `for_each_in_tup3` does not. I do not understand why this will not compile, but both GCC 9.2 and VC v142 agrees that it is wrong.

Why is this not valid syntax?

This example:

```
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

template< typename Tuple, size_t N = 0>
void for_each_in_tup1( Tuple&& tup ) {
    if constexpr(N < tuple_size<decay_t<Tuple>>::value)
        for_each_in_tup1<Tuple, N + 1>(forward<Tuple>(tup));
}

template< template<typename...> typename Tuple, typename... Ts>
void for_each_in_tup2( const Tuple<Ts...>& tup) {
}

template< template<typename...> typename Tuple, typename... Ts>
void for_each_in_tup3( Tuple<Ts...>&& tup) {
}

void test_lazy() {
    tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t> tup;
    for_each_in_tup1(tup);
    for_each_in_tup2(tup);
    for_each_in_tup3(tup);
}
```

fails with:

```
<source>:20:22: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int>&&' to lvalue of type 'std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int>'
   20 |     for_each_in_tup3(tup);
      |                      ^~~

<source>:15:39: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void for_each_in_tup3(Tuple<Ts ...>&&) [with Tuple = std::tuple; Ts = {unsigned int, unsigned int}]'
   15 | void for_each_in_tup3( Tuple<Ts...>&& tup) {
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:24,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:24,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:24,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:24),source:'%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3C+typename+Tuple,+size_t+N+%3D+0%3E%0Avoid+for_each_in_tup1(+Tuple%26%26+tup+)+%7B%0A++++if+constexpr(N+%3C+tuple_size%3Cdecay_t%3CTuple%3E%3E::value)%0A++++++++for_each_in_tup1%3CTuple,+N+%2B+1%3E(forward%3CTuple%3E(tup))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3C+template%3Ctypename...%3E+typename+Tuple,+typename...+Ts%3E%0Avoid+for_each_in_tup2(+const+Tuple%3CTs...%3E%26+tup)+%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3C+template%3Ctypename...%3E+typename+Tuple,+typename...+Ts%3E%0Avoid+for_each_in_tup3(+Tuple%3CTs...%3E%26%26+tup)+%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+test_lazy()+%7B%0A++++tuple%3Cuint32_t,+uint32_t%3E+tup%3B%0A++++for_each_in_tup1(tup)%3B%0A++++for_each_in_tup2(tup)%3B%0A++++for_each_in_tup3(tup)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:48.677819751753916,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:63.3147113594041,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:36.6852886405959,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:51.322180248246084,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `for_each_in_tup1` you are using *forwarding reference*:

```
template< typename Tuple, size_t N = 0>
void for_each_in_tup1( Tuple&& tup )
```

when you pass lvalue, `Tuple` is deduced to be `Tuple&`, and after reference collpasing you will get `for_each_in_tup1(Tuple&)`. lvalue can be bound to lvalue reference, that is why this code works. If you passed rvalue into `for_each_in_tup1`, parameter would be `Tuple&&`, and it could accept only rvalues.

In `for_each_in_tup3` there is normal rvalue reference, which can bind only rvalues.
To call `for_each_in_tup3` you have to cast `tup` to rvalue for example by `std::move`:

```
for_each_in_tup3(std::move(tup));
```

Comment: More on the subject: [temp.deduct.call/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#3)